# Mongodb server start for latest version

Tags: mongodb

I followed all the steps for installing which could be found here https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows/ and got:

"The program cant start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. "

MSI file name :- mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.4.1-signed.msi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to run Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757252/failed-to-run-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Just install this component: "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015" from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 (about 14MB) and install it. This helps.