# Failed to run Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have installed mongodb, and also created data/db folders and also add this path

> "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin"
>
> in
>
> "Computer Properties>Advanced system setting>Environment Variables>path"

as I saw in [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videos/nodejs_online_training/nodejs_mongodb.htm).

However, when I'm running "mongo" command in my cmd it throws an error that

> the program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is
> missing from your computer. Try to reinstall the program to fix the
> problem.

What is the possible solution to this problem?

Comment: Solution is here (faced with this problem on Win7)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467351/mongodb-server-start-for-latest-version/42004907#42004907

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the KB2999226 (Universal CRT) which is part of the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 failed to install.

**Fix:**

1. Download by clicking below link according to your operating system

   For Windows 64-bit ---------> [vc_redist.x64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/c/b/8cb4af84-165e-4b36-978d-e867e07fc707/vc_redist.x64.exe)

   For Windows 32-bit ---------> [vc_redist.x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/b/3/9b3d2920-49f7-4e76-a55c-d72b51e44537/vc_redist.x86.exe)
2. Install vc_redist.x64.exe or vc_redist.x64.exe
3. Restart your system.
4. Finally, you can install your program which have massage can't start
   because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to install api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll, try re-installing mongo and see if it solves your problem

Comment: Yes. Uninstall and Install again.

Comment: After doing this still i am facing same problem

Comment: Did you locate where api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is?