# "mongo -version" and "mongod --version" commands cannot be run successfully from the hyper terminal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dll, hyperterminal

I have installed mongo DB in my PC running on windows 8.1, 64bit and tried to complete the setup through hyper terminal command line but got stuck with the below errors

> Niyog@Lenovo-PC MINGW64 ~
> $ mongo -version
> C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.2/bin/mongo.exe: error while loading shared libraries: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have gone through the below post and tried the solution mentioned in it and many other posts as well but the issue persisted
[Failed to run Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757252/failed-to-run-mongodb)

****I tried the below workarounds:****

- Updated windows to the latest
- Uninstalled all the Visual C++ Redistributables, restarted the PC and reinstalled Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 to 2019

As the above steps didn't work, I have downloaded the below standalone .dll files corresponding to the current OS version and copied to System32 directory even though I am unsure about it's use

api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

Now the error is gone, but still the mongo version is not displayed in the command prompt and showing blank while executing the below commands. My aim is to integrate mongoDB to VS code file once the server is up and running

> Niyog@Lenovo-PC MINGW64 ~ $ mongo -version
>
> Niyog@Lenovo-PC MINGW64 ~ $ mongod --version

Please help me to resolve this as I have already done everything that I could do and pardon if there is some ambiguities in the question as this is my first post on the stackoverflow and I am a complete beginner